# Consent Scope for Dynamics 365 Discovery Web Api

Tags: azure-active-directory, dynamics-365

Does anybody know what consent scope is required to call the Dynamics 365 Global Discovery Web API (https://globaldisco.crm.dynamics.com/api/discovery/v2.0/) from a SPA?

I'm able to authenticate and call the actual Dynamics 365 Web API but not the globaldiscovery web API because I don't have the correct consent scopes set

Comment: Do you have a chance to look into my answer? Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Global Discovery Authentication document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/webapi/discovery-orgsdk-to-webapi#authentication), it will finally redirect you to [Create an application registration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/walkthrough-register-app-azure-active-directory#create-an-application-registration).

The required delegated permission is **user_impersonation**:
[image]

And based on [Giving access to Common Data Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/common-data-service/authenticate-oauth#giving-access-to-common-data-service):

> If your app will use Server-to-Server (S2S) authentication, this step
>   is not required. That configuration requires a specific system user
>   and the operations will be performed by that user account rather than
>   any user that must be authenticated.

Comment: Apologies I’ve been on another project this week; I will look at this and get back to you - but this is probably correct based on my other research